# Howto call management services on WSO2 DAS if using SAML SSO federated authentication provided by WSO2 IS

Tags: web-services, saml-2.0, wso2-das, wso2-identity-server

If I enable federated authentication on WSO2 DAS by using the SAML2SSOAuthenticator then if I call the management APIs (for example https://das.local:9443/services/EventStreamAdminService) it always return this message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Value>axis2ns1:50977</soapenv:Value>
         </soapenv:Code>
         <soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Access Denied. Please login first.</soapenv:Text>
         </soapenv:Reason>
         <soapenv:Detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any idea howto make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Until now there is no way to do this. The only workaround i can fin was to avoid using SAML by configuring the same user and tenant database used by the SSO provider to be used by the WSO2 product.